# Sublime text 2, setting key bindings for uploading files with SFTP

Tags: ftp, sublimetext2, text-editor

just switched to sublime and have installed the SFTP package.

What i want is to be able to do is: shift + command + U and then that will uploaded the file i am viewing.

I have looked in the key bindings file and saw this:

```
    { "keys": ["super+ctrl+u","super+ctrl+f"], "command": "sftp_upload_file" },
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+u","super+ctrl+r"], "command": "sftp_upload_folder" },
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+u","super+ctrl+y"], "command": "sftp_sync_up" },
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+u","super+ctrl+n"], "command": "sftp_upload_open_files" },
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+u","super+ctrl+m"], "command": "sftp_monitor_file" },
```

But that makes no sense to me.

They all start with the same "super+ctrl+u" I cant seem to find any information about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Each of those keybindings are two multi-key presses.

I.E. Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> at the same time, then release, then press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> at the same time.

Or, if you don't like those, remap the commands to different keybindings.